# 'Use of Undeclared Identifier' in AppDelegate (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate, undeclared-identifier

Running into a bit of an issue.

This is my first time really dealing significantly with an AppDelegate.h/.m file.

I've declared a property `@property float centerFreq` in AppDelegate.h. Then I synthesize it in AppDelegate.m like so: `@synthesize centerFreq = _centerFreq`. However, when I try to actually use `centerFreq` later on in AppDelegate.m, I get the error "Use of undeclared identifier 'centerFreq'". I don't understand why I can't use this variable anywhere in my .m file.

Comment: It's _centerFreq not centerFreq

Answer (score 1):

`foo = self.centerFreq` will call the getter that is automatically created.  Equivalent to `foo = [self centerFreq]`. `_centerFreq` will access the instance variable (iVar) directly.  In general, if you have created an `@property` you want to use the accessor methods `centerFreq` and `setCenterFreq`, which are called if you use `self.centerFreq` as the lvar or rvar in an assignment operation. (`self.centerFreq = foo` calls `[self setCenterFreq:foo]`).

`@synthesize centerFreq = _centerFreq` is unnecessary unless you have implemented both the getter and setter methods for the `@property`, as _centerFreq is the default name for the backing iVar.  If you wanted to choose a different name for the iVar, then @synthesize would be useful.

Comment: When I try to do this, it says "use of undeclared identifier 'self'". I didn't think I had to declare self anywhere...I thought it just was?

Comment: Your method declaration may be C function format rather than Objective-C method format (you need a - before the return type for an instance method) or you may just have some other syntax error.  Impossible to say for sure without code.

Comment: Ah, well that's the issue, then. The method is written in C. This poses an interesting problem, though, because I'm using a Core Audio struct that needs to be in C- I may be better off asking it separately. Thank you for your help.